# ¿Cómo especificar el separador de decimal en C#?

Tags: c#, i18n

Tengo un dilema, mayormente el separador de decimal (al convertir un `string` en `double`) que agarra un programa es el que esta establecido en el sistema operativo, ahora bien, yo tengo un app winform y quiero que el separador de decimal que agarre no sea del sistema operativo si no sea configurado en la misma app.

Entonces la pregunta seria ¿En código, cómo establezco el separador de decimales que debe utilizar la aplicación?.

Comment: Disculpe, pero que quiere decir con "SO"? Conozco "Stack Overflow" pero eso ya no es el asunto...

Comment: SO = Sistema Operativo

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar `NumberFormatInfo`

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class NumberFormatInfoSample {

   public static void Main() {

      // NumberFormatInfo asociado con la cultura en-US.
      NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo( "en-US", false ).NumberFormat;

      // Mostrar un valor con el separador por defecto (".").
      Int64 myInt = 123456789;
      Console.WriteLine( myInt.ToString( "N", nfi ) );

      // Mostrar el mismo valor con un espacio como el separador.
      nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = " ";
      Console.WriteLine( myInt.ToString( "N", nfi ) );

   }
}


/* 
Salida:

123,456,789.00
123,456,789 00
*/
```

Más info en [NumberFormatInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ahi veo como convertir de numero a cadena, y que al convertir se especifique el separador, pero lo que yo necesito es al rebes, que al convertir una cadena a un double especificar el separador. Y lo mas importante de todo (tal vez lo único), como hago para que todos los numeros que se maneje en toda la solución agarren el punto como separador de decimal?. saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Pos aqui encontre la respuesta:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/b28bx3bh(v=vs.110).aspx

Saludos

Comment: Hola RSillerico, si encontraste la respuesta por favor no dejes únicamente un link sino detalla la respuesta aquí mismo de manera que otros se beneficien de tu solución, y luego regresa para escoger como aceptada tu propia respuesta.

Comment: Mmmmmm bueno simplemente deseaba configurar una aplicación windows form para que maneje el separador de decimal independientemente del Sistema Operativo, bueno con la explicación del link se logra eso. Saludos